# dpkg: How to remove a package and all other packages which depend on it?

Tags: kde, dpkg

I tried to remove KDE from my system.
When I run `dpkg -r kdebase-bin`, it says `kdebase-data` depends on it. So how can I remove all the packages related to KDE?

Comment: I found this does the work:

`apt-get remove kdebase-bin`

it will resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually one uses a higher-level utility instead of **dpkg**. You can use **apt-get** to remove a package and all its dependencies.

```
apt-get remove <package>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
dpkg -r --force-depends  $pkg
apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 5):

Unlike `apt-get`, `aptitude` can recursively remove packages which were installed as dependencies, but which are no longer depended on when the requested removal happens.  You have to have installed those packages with `aptitude` in order for this to work, though.

There are also tools like `deborphan` which can identify packages which may no longer be necessary on your system, even if you didn't use `aptitude` to install them.  However, you have to supply it with a list of packages you do want on your system, but it's usually a quick job (there will be fewer packages it has to ask about than you might imagine).

Comment: great point. Anyway, I set the answer to Kurt's, that resolved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: But there's also `apt-get autoremove`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove package and its dependencies, use `purge`

Check all dependencies with following command

```shell
# sudo dpkg --list | grep <package-name>
```

Remove packages and its dependencies

```
# sudo apt purge <package>
```

Comment: Purging packages will remove more than the package and its dependencies... Purging may result in complete loss of the package... Never purge a package if you want to use it again in the future!

Comment: The question mentions to remove `package + all dependent packages` so I think `purge` is the appropriate command for this purpose.

Comment: `apt remove` also removes package + it's dependencies.

Comment: With `remove` config files remains in the system.