# Why are KDE components being installed/updated on 12.04 with GNOME?

Tags: gnome, kde

I am not yet fully versed with the components installed by default on my machine, so I will apologize in advance if my question is silly. [image: This screenshot] shows that a lot many of (what I assume are) KDE components (`libk*`, `kde*`, etc.) are being installed/updated on my machine. That is just the output from `sudo apt-fast update && sudo apt-fast dist-upgrade -y` from a few minutes ago.

1. Can anyone tell me why?
2. Can I safely remove them? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

System specs: Fully updated Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 w/kernel3.4, Gnome, Unity, Core2Duo, 4GB

Comment: Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): command: `dpkg --list`

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. As requested by izx, here is the output from `dpkg --list`: http://pastebin.com/BcuABbCW. Please note that this was generated today, and I spent some time last night manually removing a lot of the KDE packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably installed a KDE app at some time in the past, which needed to pull in those libraries to run.

The KDE apps would be shown in either synaptic or the Software Center, and if you're not careful, you could easily install one without realizing it.

Edit: How to remove KDE components

I don't know if there is one command that will work, but according to [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/q/72290/39753), you may be able to run `sudo apt-get remove kdebase-bin`.

Also, in synaptic, you can search all installed packages and filter on "KDE" to get a list of any installed packages that *mention* KDE, but it would need to be checked to make sure it's not just a Gnome program that says something such as "like the KDE program", for example.  But it's a graphical way to see and select installed KDE components.

There are also long commandlines that can be copied and pasted to delete everything KDE, such as the ones on [this site](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu).

Comment: The most recent application I installed was Klavaro, and it seems to be a GNOME based app. How do I check the KDE application(s) on this machine?

Comment: Klavaro is not the Kulprit, but often KDE apps do start with "K".  I know how to check before installing in Synaptic (using properties), and if you use synaptic, you may be able to search some of the candidates you listed, and check the properties for installed files and find something.  Or maybe filter installed apps with KDE and see what shows up.  Synaptic has a lot of capabilities, but since I don't have anything KDE, I can't really confirm anything.

Comment: I think I remember now; I was facing [this issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148334/lost-system-settings-on-ubuntu-precise-pangolin-x86-64), and had tried to manually install System Settings (when I remember the KDE version somehow got installed). I had fixed the system using the provided answer there and forgotten all about it. Now: how do I remove everything KDE?

Comment: I added some information to my post on removing KDE.  I've never personally done this, though, and you should pay attention to what the commands say they are going to do, to make sure it doesn't do something you don't want.  You can also uninstall the components individually as you find them; they won't really hurt anything, and you'll eventually get rid of all of them.

Comment: As Marty says, you _should_ pay attention because you most likely are already in **sudo** mode.

Answer (score 2):

You should first figure out what is pulling those packages in. You can do so from the command line for each of the packages. Giving one example:

```
apt-cache rdepends kdoctools
```

should list all packages requiring the `kdoctool` package ("rdepends" = "reverse depends"), but regardless whether they are installed or not. So for each "reverse dependency" listed, you can then check whether it is installed, using `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -l <packagename>
```

If `dpkg` cannot find that packagename, it never has been installed. If the output line starts with "ii", the package is installed (and you should *not* remove kdoctools in this example). In all other cases, the package is not installed either ("un" e.g. means "uninstalled").

You could also check with apt-get's `autoremove` parameter, e.g.

```
apt-get autoremove --purge
```

This would try to remove dependencies which were once pulled in but are no longer needed, and purge relevant configuration files (you can ommit the `--purge` if you're afraid of that part).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you did install some package that needs this KDE packages.

You can remove them but carefully look on what gets removed due to the dependencies.