# Adobe Digital Editions ADE 4.5.4 + wine doesn't work

Tags: wine, adobe

I have installed wine and installed Adobe Digital Editions (ADE 4.5). When I started the icon ADE 4.5 nothing happened. Only this old version ADE 1.7 worked. But ADE 1.7 does not work with my ebook reader, kobo aura edition 2.

I have Googled for help with "Adobe Digital Editions installations under Linux" But all information I find is old.

When using winetricks, I get `You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX` and a lot that I didn't understand.

Might it be a 32-bit / 64-bit problem or a wrong window version under wine causing the newest ADE 4.5.4 not to work?

---

I tried what you suggested, but I get `E: Paket winehq-devel` could not be found.
The same with `winehq-stable`

It was the same when changing to standard sources: http://packages.linuxmint.com http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu 
I have Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Comment: This sounds more like a WINE bug report than a problem with Ubuntu

Comment: Close voters. This question has been [answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/900149/225694)

Comment: @ElderGeek seems to be off-topic though - see the last line.

Comment: @Zanna, that edit wasn't by the OP and wasn't there when I answered. I rolled it back.

Comment: @ElderGeek see the revisions and the deleted answer to see who made the edit and why :) Rolled again!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Wine Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33276) Version 4.5 works well with the development version 2.5 of wine. Instruction on how to obtain and install this version is available [here.](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

In a nutshell, the steps are as follows:

**Preparation:**

If you have previously installed a Wine package from another repository, please [remove it and any packages that depend on it](https://askubuntu.com/q/72290/225694) (e.g., wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) before attempting to install the WineHQ packages, as they may cause dependency conflicts.

Your system will require [Multiarch support](https://askubuntu.com/a/736651/225694)

**Add the repository:**

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

**Update packages and install:**

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel`

You will notice some differences between the distro packages and the winehq builds. For more on this see the [details.](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

According to winehq [Ubuntu Multiarch support is still incomplete](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), so there may be further hoops to jump through that I am unable to test at present. The most current information I could find on this topic can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec)

Sources:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33276

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

[dpkg: How to remove a package and all other packages depend on it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72290/225694)

https://askubuntu.com/a/736651/225694

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec

Comment: Wait, we're already to WINE 2.5? v2.0 only got released a couple months ago!

Comment: @AndroidDev Time flies, doesn't it?